# Django: send notifications at user based on database change

Tags: python, django, database

I have 3 database tables:

- users (stores info about users e.g. email, name)
- metadata (stores data)
- activity (stores changes made to users/metadata tables)

I want to achieve the following:

- to store any change into the activity table (e.g. new user is created, a user updates the metadata table)
- to send notifications to users whenever a change into the users/metadata tables happens.

What are the libraries/method that I could use in order to achieve the desired functionalities? Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/

Answer (score 0):

in addition to `django signals` which wes already recommended, you can also check out `django channels` + `django activity stream`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are making use of the Django Models, I would use the Django Signals for saving the data to a second model: "MetaData" according to your question.

Specifically the `post_save` signal:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def post_save_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Save Stuff To Metadata Model.
    meta = MetaData(user=instance)
    meta.save()
```

You need to import those signals inside your `models.py` placed at the bottom of the file.

---

As for the notifications, I would follow @kristina's advice and use Django Channels.

Just remind that your application needs to be ASGI (Async). So your application server needs to be one like [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/), [daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne), [hypercorn](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/hypercorn), etc.